# Get folders from list using SharePoint Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I allowed the creation of folders in the list, and the content type "DinamicoFolder" is of type folder.
[image]

I have multiple folders inside the folder "Contas à Ordem"
[image]

URL: `https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/dinamico/Negocio/OfertaParticulares/_api/web/lists('94e42b17-3fa0-4057-84e2-1fde65ea735c')/items`

How can I get the first folder? and the folders inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While what Rob is suggesting will certainly work, you can also just get to the folders directly.  Initially, make a query for the root folder of the library you are working with:

```
https://server/sites/your/site/_api/web/lists('your-guid')/rootfolder
```

or

```
https://server/sites/your/site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('library name')/rootfolder
```

In the result of that query, you will see it has a property

```
d.Folders.__deferred.uri
```

That URI is an absolute URL, so use that as your next query to get the subfolders of the root folder.  This will return your "Contas a Ordem" folder, as well as the default "Forms" folder.  But if you look at the properties on your "Contas a Ordem" folder, you will see that it also has a `Folders.__deferred.uri` property that you can use in your next query to get the subfolders of "Contas a Ordem".

And once you get those, you will see that they each also have a `Folders.__deferred.uri` property that you can use to get *their* subfolders, and so on and so on.

Incidentally, you will also see that all the folder objects returned also have a `Files.__deferred.uri` property that will give you a URI to get the files inside that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I cover this and more in [SharePoint REST API and Lists with Folders](https://www.paitgroup.com/blog/sharepoint-rest-api-and-lists-with-folders)

Requesting the Items collection for the list will bring back all items and folders regardless of what folder they are in. You can use the FileSystemObjectType or ContentType property to determine if the item is or is not a folder. In the example below I'm using the FileSystemObjectType.

```
function getItemsOrFolders(fileSystemObjectType) {
    var appUrl = GetUrlKeyValue("SPAppWebUrl");
    var hostUrl = GetUrlKeyValue("SPHostUrl");

    var message = jQuery("#message");
    message.text("Working on it...");

    var url = appUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)" +
        "/Web/Lists/getByTitle('FolderTest')/Items?$select=*,FileDirRef&" +
        "@target='" + hostUrl + "'";

    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });
    call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var fileOrFolderText = "files";
        if (fileSystemObjectType == SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder) {
            fileOrFolderText = "folders";
        }
        message.text("All " + fileOrFolderText + ":");
        message.append("<br/>");
        jQuery.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
            if (item["FileSystemObjectType"] == fileSystemObjectType) {
                message.append(String.format(
                    "Title: {0};  Number: {1};  Id: {2}; Path: {3}",
                    item["Title"], item["Number"], item["Id"], item["FileDirRef"]));
                message.append("<br/>");
            }
        });
    });
    call.fail(failHandler);
}
```

[image]