# How to get list of folders data from SharePoint List using Javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api

Can anyone please help me with that?

Suppose my list name is: **Country** in which I created 5 folders with different country names, then inside that folder I created their state names.

So scenario is that, first I want to make a dropdown of those country names and then using that dropdown I want to filter and show state name in a Data table (jQuery data table or manually created DataTable).

List screenshot: [click to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSlPi.png)

After opening folder it data is in this manner: [click to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTn9l.png)

Code Sample:

```
    function getProjectLists() {
    //    /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('EOT')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef&$filter=FSObjType eq 1
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + " /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('EOT')/items?$filter=FSObjType eq 0";
    return getAjaxResponse(url).then(function (response) {
        hotWorkPermitProjects = response.d.results;
    });
} 
function getAjaxResponse(url) {
        var def = $.Deferred();
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (response) { def.resolve(response); },
            error: function (err) { def.reject(err); }
        });
        return def.promise();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the folders inside SharePoint list using multiple ways.

- Using filter on content type
- Using filter on `FSObjType`
- Using CAML query with `GetItems` endpoint
- Using `/Folders` endpoint

Check below reference links for more detailed answers:

1. [REST with $filter for List Items in Sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/124846/rest-with-filter-for-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013/124864#124864)
2. [Get folders from list using SharePoint Rest API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/259075/get-folders-from-list-using-sharepoint-rest-api)
3. [REST API Get all folder and subfolder in one call API](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/7cdc10a0-1924-435a-b37f-9e2892dd0507/rest-api-get-all-folder-and-subfolder-in-one-call-api)

---

Also, you can fetch the list items inside particular folder using REST API, based on folder selection in dropdown.

Check **Getting all the items in a folder** section in this article: [SharePoint REST API and Lists with Folders](https://www.paitgroup.com/blog/sharepoint-rest-api-and-lists-with-folders)

Comment: Not able to get data.
Can you please paste working code.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Can you add the current code you have to your original question by editing it?

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. Code added.